# How to fix wrong calculations in Python Mode for Processing?

Tags: python, processing, jython

I try to implement a visual illustration of Pascal's triangle with Python Mode for Processing for MAC OS X. One of the necessary steps is, of course, the calculation of the binomial coefficients in each row of the triangle. I chose to do it in a recursive way instead of calculating factorials. My code works well in Jupyter, but produces different outcomes in Processing. Does anybody know why and how I can fix the problem?

```
rows = 301

pascal=[[1], [1,1]]
for i in range (rows):
    last_row = pascal[len(pascal)-1]
    next_row = [1] +[last_row[i]+last_row[i+1] for i in range(len(last_row)) if i < len(last_row)-1] +[1]
    pascal.append(next_row)

print (pascal[35][16])
```

The code produces the correct results when executed in Jupyter, but has different results in Processing. The problems begin in row 35 of the triangle (countig starts from 0). The 16th element in this row should be 4059928950 but Processing calculates -235038346. And from then on, the calculations in Processing seem to be often wrong.

Comment: What is "Processing"? The reason for the error is that Python allows arbitrarily big integers whereas it seems that you get an overflow using "Processing".

Comment: @JohanL [Processing](https://processing.org/) is a flexible software sketchbook and a language for learning how to code. Read the tag wiki [processing](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/processing/info)!

Comment: I think JohanL is on the right track: AFAIK Python Mode uses Jython so it might be a java `long` type overflow

Comment: @JohanL Processing is a development environment for visually oriented applications (https://processing.org/ - https://py.processing.org/).

Comment: Just guessing here, if the visual display that you have in mind is the Sierpinski triangle-like effect obtained by taking the coefficients mod some number -- include the modulus in the calculations, so that overflow isn't an issue.

Comment: @John Coleman You are guessing right! :-) And your suggestion is indeed what I really did to avoid the problem, but I would like to display the binomial coefficients, as well. And I have not found a workaround for the integer overflow, yet. Processing is only supporting Java integers according to the feedback of one of the contributors to Python Mode for Processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most principled approach would be to find a big integer library that you can call from Jython, but since all you need is addition, it is easy to write your own function which will take two base 10 string representations of positive integers and return the string representation of their sum:

```
rows = 301

def add_nums(s1,s2):
    #reverse strings and 0-pad to be of the same length
    s1 = s1[::-1]
    s2 = s2[::-1]
    s1 += '0'*(max(len(s1),len(s2)) - len(s1))
    s2 += '0'*(max(len(s1),len(s2)) - len(s2))
    dsum = []
    c = 0 #carry
    for d1,d2 in zip(s1,s2):
        a,b = int(d1), int(d2)
        c,r = divmod(a+b+c,10) 
        dsum.append(str(r))
    if c > 0: dsum.append('1')
    return ''.join(reversed(dsum))

pascal=[['1'], ['1','1']]
for i in range (rows):
    last_row = pascal[len(pascal)-1]
    next_row = ['1'] +[add_nums(last_row[i],last_row[i+1]) for i in range(len(last_row)) if i < len(last_row)-1] +['1']
    pascal.append(next_row)

print (pascal[35][16]) #prints 4059928950
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have implemented your code and it works well.